# Sessions and auth in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, session-state

While deveoping a site (using Forms authentication and InProc sessionstate) a frequently run into a scenario where I lose the variables stored in Session (such as Session["myVar"]), but my auth-session remains valid.

This results in some wierd behavior on my site.

Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent diffrent lifecycles for my auth and my session variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Asp.Net a Session and "Being logged in" are not the same thing.

Both are (usually) controlled by cookies, but the cookies are separate.

To control how long a Session is kept alive, please see answer by `Jonas T`.

To control how long a user remains logged in, you can use the timeOut on the `<forms ... />` element:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    ...
</system.web>
```

To get rid of your problem you should make sure that the session timeout is at least as long as the forms authentication timeout.

If you are allowing persisted cookies in forms authentication ("Remember me"), then there are no gurantees. In that case you just have to set the session timeout to "long enough" according to some criteria/specification.

**Edit**: Also check the settings on your application pool (under IIS) where the site is deployed.  And specifically check what the "`Idle Time-out`" is. If this is set low (default value is 20 minutes I think), then IIS will shut down the application pool if no request have come in during that time. That (of course) terminates whatever in-proc sessions existed.

Answer (score 1):

Forms Authentication stores its ticket in Cookie at client side or URL(if cookie is disabled).

Session variables are stored at server side with expired time. If you want your variable to be more persistent use cookie.

You can extend your session time out in web config. This is for 20 minutes.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are working with ASP.NET Form authentication/authorization then I'd suggest you to use [Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) instead of `Session` state.

Comment: Hm, I feel I should not use Profile to store temporary information though, such as an id for the last viewed product. Or should I? Whould HttpContext.Profile and HttpContext.User have the same lifecycle?

Comment: Yes. Profile data stored in database and retrieved when user is logged so I'd suggest profile state.

Comment: Doesn't "Profile" suggest storing data such as names, postalcodes etc, rather than temporary variables? Perhaps I should read up...